# Programmatically access Apple Notes contents

Tags: ios, macos

Is it possible to programmatically access Apple Notes (that is the preinstalled app in macos and ios) contents

Answer (score 15):

Notes on macOS is scriptable with AppleScript

To log out all the notes, open Script Editor and create a new script with the following, then hit the play button:

```
tell application "Notes"
  repeat with theNote in notes
    set theNoteName to name of theNote
    log theNoteName

    set theNoteBody to body of theNote
    log theNoteBody

    log "----"
  end repeat
end tell
```

Alternatively, create a text file with the contents above and save it as `notes.scpt`, then from Terminal run:

```
osascript notes.scpt
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with JS? I can't get this to work :/ `var notes = Application("notes");

var counter = 0;

console.log(notes.notes.length);

while (counter < 10) {
    for (i = 0; i < notes.notes.length; i++) {
        note = notes[i];
        console.log(note["name"]);
        console.log(note["body"]);
        counter = counter + 1;

    }
}`

Comment: It does print out the number of Notes I have..but it doesn't print out the values for the properties—can't seem to find a way to do it.

Comment: I looks like JS API looks like this
`var app = Application("Notes");

app.notes().forEach(note => {
  console.log(note.name());
});`
Kudos to https://github.com/abruneau/apple-notes-jxa/blob/master/lib/note.js for the solution