# IOS: API to import Notes

Tags: ios, contacts

As far as I can tell, there is no api in IOS to import notes from the Notes App in the way that you can import contacts from Contacts or import calendar items.

Does anyone know of a way to import notes or is it impossible?

Comment: I'm not aware of any (but that doesn't count for much), but you might be able to share from Notes to your App

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding (after searching here and Google) is that, there was no public API, so the kind of access that EventKit allows for Reminders and Calendar was not allowed for Notes. Am I right, there wasn't any API for that.

All applications are sandboxed so you can not access the Users notes that they created in the Notes Application.

Notes on macOS is scriptable with AppleScript
[Programmatically access Apple Notes contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43704434/programmatically-access-apple-notes-contents)